# custom Section data need to update on cart item delete in magento2

Tags: magento2, custom, ajax, section

I have created custom section data called test

and create sections.xml file with below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
      <action name="*">
          <section name="test"/>
      </action>
  </config>
```

But it's not updated on cart item delete

So I have added below line as well and tried but not working

```
 <action name="checkout/cart/delete">
    <section name="test"/>
 </action>
```

can anyone help on this?

Comment: Have you define test section?

Comment: yup @RohanHapani

Comment: can you add that code here?

Comment: Don't use <action name="*">, this is a performance killer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register for the section first. File location: **etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPoolInterface">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="sectionSourceMap" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="your-custom-section" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\CustomerData\LastOrderedItems</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Use your class for **Magento\Sales\CustomerData\LastOrderedItems**

Now you can use:

```
<action name="checkout/cart/delete">
    <section name="your-custom-section"/>
</action>
<action name="checkout/sidebar/removeItem">
    <section name="your-custom-section"/>
</action>
```

Check the example from **vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/frontend/di.xml**